# How to fetch all the even lines and odd lines from a file and save them into two different files such as Evenfile & Oddfile?

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, vim, vi

Suppose I've a file named "a.txt" and it has 100 lines. Now I want to extract odd lines i.e lines 1,3,5...etc and save them to a different file such as Odd.txt and the same thing for all even lines to save them in the even.txt file keeping the source file as it is.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '{ print > (NR % 2 ? "odd.txt" : "even.txt") }' a.txt
```

This reads from `a.txt` and appends lines to either `odd.txt` or `even.txt` depending on the current line number.

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
sed -ne 'w odd.txt' -e 'n; w even.txt' a.txt
```